# Javascript to display list of image names

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a piece of javascript that, when a button is clicked, scans through a page and returns a list of image names in a list.
e.g.
image1.png
image2.jpg
image3.png

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This consists of various steps, what exactly are you having problems with? What have you tried so far? We won't just write the code for you.

Comment: This is what I have so far.
I would like to make it a bookmarklet.
<a class="button" title="one" href="javascript:var x=function{
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');var t = "";
for (var i=0, n=imgs.length;i<n;i++)
 t += '+imgs[i].src+';
return t;
}
x();
">test</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getImgSources() {
    var i = 0, dil = document.images.length, a = [], src;
    for (; i < dil; i++) {
        src = document.images[i].src;
        a.push(src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    }
    return a;
}
```

This is a very simple solution. Tell me if you need something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
getElementsByTagNames('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, something like this?

```
var getAllImages = function(){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.images).map(function(x){return x.src});
}
```

Comment: No need to use `slice`, you can directly use `Array.prototype.map.call(document.images, ...)`. I thought about using a solution like this, but then again, it can be slow if the collection is big. And it doesn't natively work in IE8 and older.